# Disable drop on empty cells using redips drag

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am using redips drag class to be able to drag/drop table cells of my table.
I would like to add a condition to forbid the drop if the destination cell was empty. Which means I only need to "switch" if the target cell is not empty.
Any help ?

```
if (target_elements_length) {
                    // call myhandler_switched because clone_limit could call myhandler_clonedend1 or myhandler_clonedend2
                    REDIPS.drag.myhandler_switched();
                    // and myhandler_dropped
                    REDIPS.drag.myhandler_dropped(target_cell);
                    // if object is cloned, update climit1_X or climit2_X classname
                    if (cloned_flag === 1) {
                        clone_limit();
                    }
                }
                // otherwise element is dropped to the empty cells
                else {
                         //TODO cancel the event.
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind ...
this is the solution. 
Modify drag.js accordingly:

```
 if (target_elements_length) {
                    obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
                    target_cell.appendChild(obj);
                    // call myhandler_switched because clone_limit could call myhandler_clonedend1 or myhandler_clonedend2
                    REDIPS.drag.myhandler_switched();
                    // and myhandler_dropped
                    REDIPS.drag.myhandler_dropped(target_cell);
                    // if object is cloned, update climit1_X or climit2_X classname
                    if (cloned_flag === 1) {
                        clone_limit();
                    }
                }
```